TYPO3 v13: Backend login after first install responds with 404
I did a fresh install via composer of the current latest v13 version (13.1.1).
The setup was fine.
But after doing my first backend login on typo3.my.domain.com/typo3 the AJAX-preflight and the request to /typo3/login?loginProvider=XXXX returned a plain apache (not a typo3 one) 404 error.
I can access the install-tool and it shows no errors on the environment checks. So I guess the installation is fine.
After reading throughout the internet I somehow suspect the .htaccess file, since the request seems not to land in any php file.
I checked the TYPO3 and Apache logs, which both have no output.
I might try installing the latest v12 and see if the same problem persists. (Update: same problem exists also with TYPO3 12.4.16 LTS)
Maybe someone has already another idea?

I just figured it out:
In my httpd.conf (which I never touched before) I had the following directive:
<Directory "/var/www/html">
  ...
  AllowOverride None
  ...
</Directory>

which basically denied executing any directives in .htaccess files as far as I undestand.
So changing that line to from None to All fixed that for me.

That sounds like a missing .htaccess file.
Check, if there is a .htaccess file in your public folder. If not - copy:
vendor/typo3/cms-install/Resources/Private/FolderStructureTemplateFiles/root-htaccess
to your public folder and rename the file to .htaccess
If you have an .htaccess file in your public folder, check, if it's the same, as mentioned above.

I compared the public/.htaccess with the .../root-htaccess and they are identical. So that did not change anything, unfortunately.
